# How to get Video Spout Stream in Python

Tags: python, stream

I'm using a program (VTube Studio) that has a Spout2 option. Is it possible to get that stream in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, Spout2 is a virtual webcam-like technology, so theoretically, it should be possible to capture the stream from Spout2 using a subprocess call to ffmpeg within Python. You can use ffmpeg to capture the video frames from the Spout2 source and process them further as needed within your Python program. However, please note that the exact implementation details may vary, so it's recommended to refer to the documentation or examples provided by the Spout2 library or any related libraries you're using for capturing and processing the stream.

Comment: Also you can use the cv2.VideoCapture class from the OpenCV (cv2) library to work with video streams. The cv2.VideoCapture class provides a convenient way to capture video from various sources, including video files and video streams.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a library for Windows, but it's complicated.

https://github.com/spiraltechnica/Spout-for-Python/tree/master